# How set my app as default messaging in android?

Tags: android, sms

I want set my app as default messaging app in android 4.4 and above.in my Manifest i have some permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

But when i install my app and i want set for messaging it's Not in Default messaging app list.

How can i see my app in this list? or how can do it pro grammatically?

**Edite:**

Thanks for links but i can't solve my problem.
I have tried all 4 steps as links mentioned but still I can't see my app in default app messaging list.